# Access prototype value from prototype function

Tags: javascript

How do I access `open` array that is prototyped from `removeConnection()` function? Right now I get `ReferenceError: open is not defined` when I call the function.

```
function Connections() {}
Connections.prototype.open = [];

Object.defineProperty(Connections.prototype, 'total', {
  get: function total() {
    return this.open.length;
  }
});

Connections.prototype.removeConnection = function(res) {
  this.open = open.filter(function(storedRes) {
    if (storedRes !== res) {
      return storedRes;
    }
  });
}

var connections = new Connections();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it raises a different error `Uncaught TypeError: open.filter is not a function` and the fix is to change `this.open = open.filter` to `this.open = this.open.filter`.

See the runnable example:

```js
function Connections() {}
Connections.prototype.open = [];

Object.defineProperty(Connections.prototype, 'total', {
  get: function total() {
    return this.open.length;
  }
});

Connections.prototype.removeConnection = function(res) {
  this.open = this.open.filter(function(storedRes) {
    if (storedRes !== res) {
      return storedRes;
    }
  });
}

var connections = new Connections();

connections.open = ['one', 'two']
alert(connections.open)
connections.removeConnection('one')
alert(connections.open)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `this`.

```
Connections.prototype.removeConnection = function(res) {
  this.open = this.open.filter(function(storedRes) {
    if (storedRes !== res) {
      return storedRes;
    }
  });
}
```